# magento2: getBaseUrl() in helper class?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, base-url, geturl

I was wondering how to use the `getBaseUrl()` in controller/helper class..

anybody have idea ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the duplicate question, I'm just going to explain how to do it in an helper/controller

First you have to inject the `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` in your constructor:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct(...);
}
```

Then you can use it whenever you want in your class like this:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```